# ¿Cómo corregir el error ValueError Unknown label type?

Tags: python, array

No para de saltarme ese error

> raise ValueError("Unknown label type: %s" % repr(ys)) ValueError: Unknown label type: (array([30.99, 39.62]),)

y no encuentro como solucionarlo. Debajo adjunto mi código y los datos inventados que le estoy pasando para probarlo. Me da muchos problemas usar la función fit.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from mlxtend.feature_selection import SequentialFeatureSelector

# Cargar los datos desde un archivo CSV
data = pd.read_csv('datos2.csv',delimiter=';')

#Función para pedir al usuario qué características conoce:
def ask_user(caracteristicas):
    # Pide al usuario los índices de las características que desea utilizar y los valores que sabe
    print("Características: ", caracteristicas)
    selected_str = input("Introduce las características que conoces (separadas por comas): ")
    selected = [i for i in selected_str.split(",")] #convertimos los datos que nos da el usuario en listas 
    etiqueta = input("Introduce la etiqueta que deseas predecir: ")
  
    return etiqueta, selected

caracteristicas = list(data.columns)#reservamos las caracteristicas para preguntar al usuario

# Obtener la etiqueta a predecir
etiqueta, caracteristicas = ask_user(caracteristicas)

# Separar los datos en conjuntos de entrenamiento y prueba
X = np.array(data[caracteristicas])
y = data[etiqueta].values.astype(str)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=0)

# Crear un clasificador Naive Bayes
nb = GaussianNB()

# Crear un selector de características secuenciales hacia atrás
sfs = SequentialFeatureSelector(nb, k_features=1, forward=False, verbose=0, scoring='accuracy', cv=2)

# Ejecutar la eliminación secuencial hacia atrás
sfs = sfs.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Obtener las características seleccionadas
selected_features = list(sfs.k_feature_names_)

# Crear un nuevo conjunto de datos solo con las características seleccionadas
X_train_selected = X_train[selected_features]
X_test_selected = X_test[selected_features]

# Entrenar el modelo Naive Bayes con las características seleccionadas
nb.fit(X_train_selected, y_train)

# Pedir al usuario las características que conoce
print("Introduce los valores de las características conocidas (separados por comas):")
user_input = input()
user_input = user_input.split(",")
X_user = pd.DataFrame([user_input], columns=caracteristicas)

# Realizar las predicciones en el conjunto de datos X_user
y_pred = nb.predict(X_user[selected_features])

# Mostrar la predicción al usuario
print("-----------------------------------------------------------")
print("Predicción de etiqueta: ", y_pred[0])

# Realizar la predicción en el conjunto de prueba y calcular la precisión del modelo
y_pred_test = nb.predict(X_test_selected)
precision = accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred_test)

# Mostrar la precisión del modelo
print("Precisión: {:.2f}%".format(precision*100))
```

2013;2011;2010;2006;2001;1996

65.36;64.17;65.19;50.74;39.62;31.38

55.74;53.31;52.07;38.83;24.79;18.91

54.15;52.95;52.17;39.8;31.59;27.88

61.03;60.45;54.48;50.39;27.17;19.54

62.46;63.49;59.7;47.99;30.99;27.62

56.99;53.98;42.37;37.45;27.40;12.32

Comment: ¿En qué línea ocurre el error?  ¿Cual es el resultado esperado?

Comment: *Introduce las características que conoces (separadas por comas): * ¿Que se supone hay que responder?

Comment: @CandidMoe las caracteristicas son la primera linea del csv, lo que se muestra como opcion por ejemplo pones que conoces : 2013,2011,2001

Después la etiqueta es el valor que deseas predecir, por ejemplo a raiz de los datos que sabes quieres saber 2006 (decir que el csv es para probar simplemente en este caso no hay coherencia en datos, es inventado rapido por mi)

La linea que da el error es el ```sfs = sfs.fit(X_train, y_train)```

Answer (score 0):

cambia     y = np.array(data[etiqueta]).ravel() por esto

```
y = data[etiqueta].values.astype(str)
```

creo que tu error se produce porque la variable y tiene varias etiquetas o no tiene el formato correcto. Es posible que la función .ravel() utilizada para aplanar la matriz y no haya funcionado como se esperaba.

Comment: gracias por responder.
Lo he cambiado y ahora me da este problema:
**ValueError: n_splits=2 cannot be greater than the number of members in each class.**

He cambiado cv=1 y entonces me dice:
**ValueError: k-fold cross-validation requires at least one train/test split by setting n_splits=2 or more, got n_splits=1.**

Con cv=3 da el mismo problema que cv=2.